# Classic ASP xmlhhtp between < head> < /head> tags only

Tags: asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

With classic ASP, i retrieve data from an another webpage with XMLHTTP, and save it to database.

```
private function gethttp(url)
Set strhttp=server.createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
strhttp.Open "get",url,false
strhttp.send
gethttp=strhttp.responsetext
Set strhttp=Nothing
End function  


url="http://www.noktadomains.com/buydomains/BodyBalance#BodyBalancing.com"  
text=gethttp(url)

response.write(text)
```

is it possible only call source between **< head>...< /head>** tags?
Because the whole page is very large and takes too long to load, and i do not need the **< html>...< /html>** part of it !!

Thanks

Comment: Hello. I'm running out of time, so take a look around for `selectSingleNode` using XMLHTTP. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to just extract the HEAD section out, like this?

(Add this code to the end of your function)

```
intStart = InStr(text, "<head>)
If intStart <> 0 Then
    intStart = intStart + 6
    intEnd = InStr(intStart, text, "</head>")
    If intEnd <> 0 Then
        text = Mid(text, intStart, intEnd - intStart)
    End If
End If
```